# react js : how to extract time from todays date in react js

Tags: reactjs

Mon Oct 04 2021 17:13:49 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) i have date and time in this format how can i extrract  17:13:49 from this that is the time and convert into 5:13:49

```
const [timerState, setTimerState] = useState();

 setTimerState({ ...timerState, start: new Date() });
```

Comment: use new Date().getHour() and new Date().getMinutes()

Comment: start: new Date() how will i replace here?

Comment: or you can use moment.js as well

Comment: https://momentjs.com/

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
start: new Date().toLocaleString('en-IN').split(' ')[1]
```